# Identical Functions, both get executed, no Sound in one

Tags: objective-c, xcode, audio

I'v googled the problem but couldn't find a similar case.

I've used this tutorial to play the testSound.mp3 - File when hitting a button on the iPad-Simulator:
http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/

It works  that way (it plays the sound), if the playSound-Method is in my ViewController.m, but not in my Sound.m (which has a identical method).
The Code gets executed (NSLog says: "Sound.m playSound executed"), but there is no sound at all.

I'd really appreciate some help here, guess I'm totally stuck... :(

Best regards,
- Teapot

//  ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "Sound.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

}

- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender;
- (void)playSound: (NSString*) soundFile volume : (NSInteger) volume repeats : (NSInteger) repeats;

@end
```

//  ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading thea view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender {

    NSLog (@"Method: pressButton");

    [self playSound: @"testSound.mp3" volume: 2 repeats: 2 url : url]; //It works!

    Sound *tempSound = [[Sound alloc] init];
    [tempSound playSound: @"testSound.mp3" volume: 2 repeats: 2]; // Doesn't work. -> Says "Sound.m playSound executed", but there is no Sound.

}

- (void)playSound: (NSString*) soundFile volume : (NSInteger) volume repeats : (NSInteger) repeats {

    NSLog(@"ViewControler playSound");

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

    if (audioPlayer == nil){
        NSLog([error description]);
        NSLog(@"ViewController.m playSound NOT executed");
    }
    else{
        [audioPlayer play];
        NSLog(@"ViewController.m playSound executed");
    } 

}

@end
```

//  Sound.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface Sound : NSObject {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

- (void) playSound: (NSString*) soundFile volume : (NSInteger) volume repeats : (NSInteger) repeats;

@end
```

//  Sound.m

```
#import "Sound.h"

@implementation Sound

- (void)playSound: (NSString*) soundFile volume : (NSInteger) volume repeats : (NSInteger) repeats {

    NSLog(@"Sound playSound");

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

    if (audioPlayer == nil){
        NSLog([error description]);
        NSLog(@"Sound.m playSound NOT executed");
    }
    else{
        [audioPlayer play];
        NSLog(@"Sound.m playSound executed");
    } 

}

@end
```

Comment: what is the url, jst can u show me?

Comment: what the hell r u doing here? have u really checked this code?

Comment: Hello murali, I've checked it and renamed some things afterward. The url-output (via absoluteString) is kind of strange, at some point it shows thousands of Chinese letters. Didn't know what to make out of that but after Martin R's answer it seems not to be the problem after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some inconsistencies in your code: `playSound:` has an `NSString` parameter, but `AVAudioPlayer` inside that method uses a `NSURL`. Then you set `numberOfLoops = -1` (which means infinite repetition) instead of `numberOfLoops = repeat`.

But the **main problem** is that here (assuming that you compile with "Automatic Reference Counting")

```
Sound *tempSound = [[Sound alloc] init];
[tempSound playSound: @"testSound.mp3" volume: 2 repeats: 2];
```

the `tempSound` object is *deallocated* when the `pressButton:` is left, because no strong references to that object exist anymore.

If you add an instance variable (or property) `sound` to the view controller class, and assign to that

```
sound = [[Sound alloc] init];
[sound playSound: @"testSound.mp3" volume: 2 repeats: 2];
```

then it should work as expected.

***Alternatively,*** you could prevent the `Sound` object from being deallocated too early by maintaining a "self reference" inside the object, which is removed only when the sound has finished playing:

```
@interface Sound () <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
@property(strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property(strong, nonatomic) Sound *selfRef;
@end

@implementation Sound

- (void)playSound:(NSString *)soundFile volume:(NSInteger)volume repeats:(NSInteger)repeats
{
    NSLog(@"Sound playSound");
    NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:soundFile withExtension:nil];
    NSError *error;
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
    if (self.audioPlayer == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
        NSLog(@"Sound.m playSound NOT executed");
    } else{
        self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = repeats;
        self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [self.audioPlayer play];
        self.selfRef = self; // self reference to avoid deallocation
        NSLog(@"Sound.m playSound executed");
    }
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    self.selfRef = nil; // remove self reference
}
@end
```

Of course, you shouldn't do this with "infinite repetition"!

Comment: Ah, I didn't consider the object's lifetime. Thank you very much, Martin R! :) And thanks again for your alternative solution!! This put my mind at ease.

Yes, haven't used repeat etc. yet. First I wanted that bug fixed.

Comment: @Teapot: You are welcome. ARC is a great feature (I always use it now), but one has to learn to "think in ARC" :-)